Monitor loses video for about 3 seconds then comes back on
I have a Surface Book Pro which I bought about 6 years ago with an Intel NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1060 video card.
It doesn't have an HDMI port, so I use a hub which doubles as a power source for the computer. I plugged the monitor's HDMI into a connector cable and into the micro-port, designed for a monitor.
Then about 3 years ago, I started working from home. I'd use the same HDMI cable for my work laptop and my Surface: I'd unplug from the work laptop when I was done for the day and plug it into my Surface after.
A few months ago, I finally found a KVM switch so I could plug 2 HMDI cables from both computers into the monitor, which worked great.
But then about 2 months ago, the monitor would randomly lose the video signal when it was connected to the Surface, and sometimes it would even display "No HDMI signal". The hub has 2 micro-ports, so I plugged the connector into the other port and it worked fine.
But the next day, it started doing the same thing when using that port: the monitor would go black and the video would display on my Surface's display, then the monitor would come back on, in the space of about 2-3 seconds. Then a few days later, the monitor went completely off, and then displayed "No HMDI signal".
Also, the light on the KVM switch went off, as if there was no signal from the Surface through the HMDI cable.
At the end of July, I bought a HDMI to USB-C connector, plugged the HDMI cable into that, and into my Surface and the problem went away.
But then about 2 weeks ago, I took my Surface to a friend's house, so I disconnected everything (USB-C, power, and USB). Ever since I came home and plugged everything back in, the same thing happens as earlier: the monitor goes black, the video is displayed on my Surface's display for about 2 seconds, and then the monitor comes back on.
I tried using the new HDMI cable that came with the KVM switch and the issue continued.
I tried connecting the HDMI cable directly into the monitor, instead of the KVM switch, and the issue continued.
I bought a brand new HDMI to USB-C cable, and the issue continued.
I ran a Windows Update a few days ago, and the issue continued.
I saw a website that suggested blowing a little air into the ports to clear out any dust, which I did, and the issue continued.
Yet when I use my work laptop, the monitor never goes off. This means the monitor, cables, and KVM switch work fine.
I went into Device Manager, clicked on the USB 3 controller and noticed it was updated 4/12/2024, but this issue started about 2 weeks ago. I also clicked Update Driver and it said "the best drivers are already installed".
I looked through a related thread and it suggested going to the NVIDIA website and downloading the latest driver as a zip file:
Monitor occasionally goes black and then comes back on again
I did that, but the site only gave me an exe file.
So I downloaded it and ran it. I said to install just the driver, not the "experience". But then after it was done installing, the monitor still went off and and back on.
I restarted my computer even though the installer didn't say it needed to be restarted, and the monitor still went off and back on.
I then unplugged the HDMI cable from the USB-C port and plugged it into the power hub, but then about 10 seconds later, the signal to the monitor went off and it said "No HDMI signal".
So I switched it back to the USB-C port and the issue continues.
Can anyone help diagnose the issue?
I tried some other things this morning:
I went through the Intel NVIDIA driver update page and I downloaded almost every Studio Driver listed on the page, going back to Feb 2024. But when I tried to install them, they all said my graphics card hardware isn't compatible with the driver.
I went to Device Manager, found the NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1060, right-clicked, and selected Disable Device. But that didn't fix it and literally 1 minute later, the monitor went off and back on.
Then I re-enabled it, though that didn't make any difference.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Two scenarios.

It seems to me that the monitor is shutting down when you switch because its not detecting anything at the other end of the HDMI cable.  Therefore the surface is doing the same. One solution is to not use the KVM switch.  I get a glitch when I try to use a KVM switch on my Windows and it re-arranges the other screens.  Instead I now have a monitor with two ports.  I have both the Windows and the Pi connected to it and I use the monitor buttons to switch between them.  You should try this.  Many monitors have multiple ports - it may have an HDMI and another different sort of port.
The surface is faulty.  Mine didn't last long, I had to throw it away.


Thanks for the idea. I've tried multiple cables and plugging the Surface into the monitor, but I get the same result. So I think you're right that the Surface developed a fault of some kind.
